# paste full class name after from ctrl+o (php)

Tags: php, netbeans, netbeans-8

Is there a way to paste full class name after searching it through ctrl+o ?

Since I work with classes with different namespaces, I'd like to be able to paste the full class name after I find the proper class, is there a way to do this in neatbeans?